# How can I create a new object in the Outliner?

Tags: modeling, objects, scene, subdivision-surface, outliner

How can I create a new object in the Outliner?
I'm using Blender for the first time and im watching this tutorial video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_X9v29i-Iw 
As you can see in 1:16 min in the video, the guy adds a cylinder.

If I add this cylinder, it doesn't appear as a new object in the outliner.

It's a problem because I used the Subdivision Surface tool on the body
The cylinder that I add there has the subdivision surface tool as well then... and it's not a cylinder anymore...

If I want to remove the subdivision tool, the body doesn't have it either then.

Comment: I have no idea what is a problem. It seems to me you are confused in terms.  For 99,9% Blender projects you will never need more than one scene. In this tutorial he just insert cylinder. You can do it by Shift+A - Mesh - Cylinder in viewport.

Comment: BTW - this is not very good way how to start learn Blender. Go for something easy and learn basics first :-)

Comment: If I add the cylinder it's just not a cylinder you know ._. And in his video, the cylinder appears under the other object in the outliner. 
In my outliner, there appears nothing.. that's why i thought it has something to do with the scene.. xd

Yeh i know its not a very good way to start with Blender - but i already have the whole body! °-° And I want to finish it >-<

Comment: Probably if added object isn't shown in the Outliner the hierarchy in it is collapsed (hidden). Show a screenshot of your Outliner window along with viewport and Properties editor windows. Cylinder with Subsurf modifier remains to be cylinder - just as any object. I think you are mixing different terms and workflows, look into basic tutorials on Blender interface first.

Comment: Heyy!! I solved my problem - I don't exactly know how but it was something with the selecting object. Thank ya all! >-< After this project, I'll look into the basics.. x-x

Comment: @Shallty Read this related link https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56153/why-cant-objects-in-edit-mode-have-their-own-name/56155#56155

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86972/is-there-a-way-to-edit-around-another-object/86974#86974

Answer (score 3):

You have to be careful in witch mode you add a new object. If you are in object mode you add the new mesh as its own object and you can see it in the outliner as its own item with its own modifiers, etc. but if you are in edit mode inside another object and you add the new mesh in edit mode it becomes part of the geometry of the object you are in edit mode of sharing that objects texture, modifiers, etc.

Comment: @Shallty Don't forget to accept as an answer if it helped you :D