# New objects keep get selected with older one

Tags: selection-tools

I created a cube and at some point added a new one. Now every time I select the new one in Object mode, the old cube gets selected with it. I thought it was because I had proportional editing toggled by accident but that doesn't seem to be the issue here. Any suggestions as to why in object mode they get selected together?

Comment: are you sure your 2 cubes are not one unique object? You may have created your second cube within the first one, believing you were in Object mode when you were actually in Edit mode...

Comment: Hah, that was it. How does this work? It feels very counter intuitive

Comment: you can create as many meshes as you want into an object, and you these meshes are primitives as well, thus the confusion. To make the second mesh its own object, select it with L and press P to separate

Comment: So an object is not in itself the visual part that you create that's just the first "Node" where things can be under it? Is this so you can create more complex things for one object and have a way to move them all together and edit them?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, actually the decision to make an object with several meshes or several objects will depends on several things, generally it's more convenient to make one object if it's one object IRL, but you may need to create several objects, for example if each part needs its own modifier, but maybe begins with a rule like one object IRL is one object in Blender?

Comment: I understand, I was thinking it might be some for of collection where you create a new object in the object tree and then you can create new children for it. For example to make a box from individual planes that you merge

Comment: read the following post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/86974/92768

Comment: Yep that clarified it. I can't mark it as an answer though if it's a comment.